# Sybase SQL Anywhere : rollback transaction with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm running CodeIgniter 2 with SQL Anywhere (I have a custom class to handle connection with SAP DLLs).

I have a problem with a transaction containing many queries.
One of them is raising an error (returned by a trigger while trying to update a table) : in that case, I want the transaction to be rollbacked at the end of the treatment, as you can see below.

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...'); //This raises an error
$this->db->trans_complete(); //A rollback is done, and should cancel the first query
```

I've tried to change following options :

- chained => Off
- continue_after_raiserror => On
- on_tsql_error => Continue

What's weird is that I'm logging my queries : executing them manually in Interactive SQL works well !
It seems that the raised error breaks the transaction.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the solution : we just need to use some functions provided by SAP PHP's DLLs (http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/php-support.html).

- begin transaction with :

  sasql_set_option($this->conn_id, 'auto_commit', 0);
- finally, if you need to commit :

  sasql_commit($conn_id);
- and if you need to rollback :

  sasql_rollback($conn_id);
  sasql_set_option($conn_id, 'auto_commit', 1);